# Prove that $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

The exercise is:

> Fix $b>1$. If $m, n, p, q$ are integers, $n>0$, $q>0$ and $r=m/n=p/q$, prove that:
>
> $$(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
>
> Hence it makes sense to define $b^r = (b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

So far, this is what I got:

Since $n,q>0$, $m$ and $p$ *must* both be positive or both be negative, or else the equality $m/n=p/q$ won't hold. Now, $m/n$ is not necessarily an integer, but $mq$ surely is. The same holds for $np$. It is trivial to see that $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}} \iff b^{mq} = b^{np}$.

*Lemma*: For every real $x>0$ and every integer $w>0$, there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^w = x$.

Proof: See Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, page 10.

Hence, $mq=np$. So, indeed $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$.

Is this proof satisfactory? Am I missing something?

Comment: I forgot a _very_ important detail, $b>1$

Comment: " It is trivial to see that $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}} \iff b^{mq} = b^{np}$"  Why the heck is that trivial?  Proving that is the single one thing you have to prove and.... I don't see any reason that you have demonstrated any reason that should be.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm an economist and still haven't quite figured out what can be thought of as trivial.

The reason I think this statement holds is because $m/n=p/q \iff mq=np$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, but what does $mq = np$ and $b^{mq} = b^{np}$ have to do with $(b^m)^{\frac 1n} = (b^p)^{\frac 1q}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea.  One minor comment is that when you write “Hence, $mq=np$”, you imply that the statement $mq=np$ follows from some immediately previous statement, such as the the lemma.  But it doesn't; it follows from the hypothesis that $m/n = p/q$.

But more importantly (IMO), this line

> It is trivial to see that $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}} \iff b^{mq} = b^{np}$

needs more explanation.  When students write that something is “trivial”, I usually take it as a bluff.  To me the point of the exercise is to use the lemma you cited to prove that $y^n = b^m \implies y^q = b^p$.  Your highlighted statement follows.

---

Addendum: Based on the comments below, I think you're still missing the point of the exercise and how the lemma is to be used.  You're right that the lemma guarantees $(b^m)^{1/n} = (b^p)^{1/q}$, but if I understand the exercise correctly, you are to *provide the details*.

The lemma tells us that every positive number *has* a $w$-th root, and how to recognize the $w$-th root of a number from its properties.  In other words, $w$-th roots exist and are unique.

What *is* $(b^m)^{1/n}$? It's the unique positive real number $y$ such that $y^n = b^m$.  Likewise, $(b^p)^{1/q}$ is the unique positive real number $z$ such that $z^q = b^p$.  To prove that $(b^m)^{1/n} = (b^p)^{1/q}$, it is sufficient to show that $y^q = b^p$ Why? And how?

Comment: Since $n,q>0$, $m$ and $p$ _must_ both be positive or both be negative, or else the equality $m/n=p/q$ won't hold. $m/n$ is not necessarily an integer, but $mq$ surely is. The same holds for $np$. It is trivial to see that $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}} \iff b^{mq} = b^{np}$, it follows from the fact that $m/n=p/q$

_Lemma_: For every real $x>0$ and every integer $w>0$, there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^w = x$. 

Proof: See Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, page 10. 

So, indeed $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$. 

Better now?

Comment: "Better now?"  No.  *HOW* does $(b^m)^{\frac 1n} = (b^p)^{\frac 1q}$ follow from $\frac mn = \frac pq$?  I'll even give you $\frac mn = \frac pq \iff mq = np$ and so $b^{mq} = b^{np}$. (BTW what does $m,n$ being positive or negative have to do with anything)  How does that imply that $(b^m)^{\frac 1n} = (b^p)^{\frac 1q}$?  It certainly isn't trivial.

Comment: By definition, $x^{1/n}=y$ implies that $x=y^n$.  We would like to show that $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^{1/n})^m$.

Let $y^m=(b^m)^{1/n}$.  From the definition, we have 

$$\begin{align}
b^m&=(y^m)^n\\\\
&=y^{mn}\\\\
&=(y^n)^m\\\\
b&=y^n\\\\
b^{1/n}&=(y^n)^{1/n}\\\\
&=y\\\\
(b^{1/n})^m&=y^m\\\\
&=(b^m)^{1/n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Alternative to Mark's comment.  $\frac mn = \frac pq \implies mq = np$.  ANd $[(b^m)^{\frac 1n}]^{np}=([(b^m)^{\frac 1n}]^n)^p = (b^m)^p = b^{mp}$ whereas $[(b^p)^{\frac 1q}]^{np} = [(b^p)^{\frac 1q}]^{mq} =([(b^p)^{\frac 1q}]^q)^m = (b^p)^m = b^{mp}$.

Comment: @MarkViola  We don't need to prove $(b^m)^{\frac 1n} = (b^{\frac 1n}^m$ (although it can't hurt).  We need to prove that $(b^m)^{\frac 1n}=(b^p)^{\frac 1q}$.

Comment: >Since $n,q>0$, $m$ and $p$ _must_ both be positive or both be negative, or else the equality $m/n=p/q$ won't hold. Now, $m/n$ is not necessarily an integer, but $mq$ surely is. The same holds for $np$. 

>_Lemma_: For every real $x>0$ and every integer $w>0$, there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^w = x$. 

>Proof: See Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, page 10. 

Can I then say that since $m/n=p/q \implies mq = np$, the lemma guarantees $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$ or is it a stretch?

Comment: @fleablood Once one proves $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^{1/n})^m=b^{m/n}$, then one has $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$ for $m/n=p/q$.

Answer (score 1):

"" It is trivial to see that $(b^m)^{\frac{1}{n}} = (b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}} \iff b^{mq} = b^{np}$""

Whether that is or is not trivial, that *is* the *one* thing you are asked to show and you must show it.  You did not.

You "lemma" is Rudin's Th. 1.21 and you need to use it twice.

Here's a hint:  Use the theorem to prove that $(b^m)^{\frac 1n}$ and $(b^p)^{\frac 1q}$ exist in the first place. Let $(b^m)^{\frac 1n} = d$ and $(b^p)^{\frac 1q} = c$.  Find an integer $k$ so that $d^k = c^k> 1$.  Use the theorem to prove $d = k$.